# django Error: Tried everything suggested by every website existing on google but still getting "The given username must be set"

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am working on user registration for an E-commerce Website
I am not using any forms.py and there is no Indentation issue. I am passing simple JSON on postman on POST method to check if it is working or not, but I am getting errors. Below is my code and my error. I will be grateful for your help.

**My model.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
import datetime

class User(AbstractUser):
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**My View.py**

```
class Register(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
        last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        confirm_password = request.POST.get('confirm_password')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        if password == confirm_password:
            if Client.objects.filter(username = username).exists():
                return Response({"message": "this username already exist"})
            elif Client.objects.filter(email = email).exists():
                return Response({"message": "This emaila address is already taken"})
            else:
                user= Client.objects.create_user(username = username, password =confirm_password, 
                                                 email=email)
                user.save()
        else:
            return Response({"message": "Try it again"}, 404)
```

**My urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from user_authentication.views import Login, Logout, Register

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', Login.as_view()),
    path('logout/', Logout.as_view()),
    path('register/', Register.as_view()),
]
```

**Error--- Exception Value:
The given username must be set**

```
Internal Server Error: /register/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\garments\user_authentication\views.py", line 40, in post
    user= Client.objects.create_user(username = username, password =confirm_password, email=email)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 152, in create_user
    return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\GitHub\E-commerce\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 137, in _create_user
    raise ValueError('The given username must be set')
ValueError: The given username must be set
```

The JSON, I am passing is:
{"username":"bilalahmed" , "first_name":"Bilal", "last_name":"Ahmed", "password":"bilal1234", "email":"bilalahmed@example.com"}

Comment: Try accessing `request.data` instead of `request.POST`? If you are posting JSON data `request.POST` might not contain what you think it does

Comment: I am importing User as Client in views.py, There is no issue of User and Client also. I am not getting the problem with the code.

Comment: Then its not creating user, the error message is "try it again"

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the failing line and inspect actual `username` value you're passing to `Client.objects.create_user`

Comment: @BismahKhalique You are not passing `confirm_password` in your data, the `if` block that checks the passwords match will always fail

Comment: oh yess!! You are so right. Thanks alot